# How do I install from grub?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a 2008 MacBook Pro. I tried six different methods for making a bootable USB thumb drive with a `mini.iso` on it, but it won't boot from it. I do have a USB with a 2013 installer that I can boot from, but I'm not sure where to go from the grub prompt.

If I do `set root='(hd0,1)'` then `linux`<kbd>tab</kbd> will autocomplete with `/efi/boot/bootx64.efi`. That autocompletes from `/` so it isn't seeing anything else as far as I can tell. Here's what's on the thumb drive:

```
ubuntu-installer/
    -initrd.gz
    -linux
efi/
boot/
    - grub
        - fonts
        - grubenv
        - i386-pc
        - locale
        - x86_64-efi
```

I ~think~ that last time I used this thumb drive we did a network install, but I had a more experienced friend with me then. Can someone point me towards how I can use this as an installer?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB

Comment: Hmm. Just read though that. Not sure it helps because there's no kernel on my thumb drive.

Comment: Erm. Actually I think that "linux" is the kernel.

Comment: Erm . Did it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things I learned, mostly by stabbing around in the dark:

- `(hd0,gpt3)` actually contained most of my files. Including the kernel at `ubuntu-installer/linux`.
- I was able to get to an installer by doing:

  ```
  root=(hd0,gpt3)
  linux /ubuntu-installer/linux
  initrd /ubuntu-installer/initrd.gz
  boot
  ```

That took me into the install process, where I got as far as choosing a mirror and I wasn't able to get any data from `us.archive.ubuntu.org` -- I was definitely connected to the internet and the network connection was confirmed but it was still giving me errors. I wound up going ahead and burning mini.iso to a CD instead.